# MySQL Access Denied even for SuperUser - ERROR 1045 (28000)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I failed to run MySQL on my machine. I didn't set password for MySQL, if I am not wrong.

I have done the following series of actions, including 1) running as user, 2) running as SuperUser, 3) running without password, and 4) running with the user password.

As you can see, I failed all of them. Why is it so?

```
abc@ubuntu:~$ mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'abc'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
abc@ubuntu:~$ sudo su
[sudo] password for abc: 
root@ubuntu:/home/abc# mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
root@ubuntu:/home/abc# mysql -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
root@ubuntu:/home/abc# mysql -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
root@ubuntu:/home/abc#
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure about your current password, set a new password:

```
# mysqladmin -u root password 'new-password'
```

then log in with your new password:

```
# mysql -u root –p
```

Comment: As a newbie, may I ask why the # is there? I have seen it here and there, and I find it basically comments off the thing behind. Am I wrong? Do I type with the #? Thanks

Comment: No, you don't have to type the #. It's just a way to suggest that you are typing the text on command line. Similar to >. Just forget about it :)

Comment: I tried `# mysqladmin -u root password 'new-password'`, but I got `mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'`

Comment: Is your mysql server started?

Comment: I am really sorry, but I am rather rather new. So could you please kindly provide a step to check this? Thanks a lot! I have been stuck here for one whole day.

Comment: No problem. I suggest you [installing LAMP following this tutorial](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-install-lamp-on-ubuntu#.UwvBfOOSwuk). When it's done you should have Apache, MySQL and PHP installed, and your mysql server should be up and running.

Then try again the command from my comment.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48308/discussion-between-farticle-pilter-and-tamas-pap)

Comment: I'm very tired now (it was a long day), but if you can't fix this, we can continue tomorrow.

Comment: Sure, no problem. Thanks a lot, I will wait for your help tomorrow. Sleep tight! :)